# What does it mean next error: 'Program type already present'

Tags: android, react-native, build, gradlew

Currently have issue with building react-native project After buildin I got next error in my console:

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>   D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives

android/build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
        ext {
            buildToolsVersion = "28"
            minSdkVersion = 16
            compileSdkVersion = 28
            targetSdkVersion = 26
            supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
        }
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
        }
    }

app/build.gradle

apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hypaship"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    subprojects {
      project.configurations.all {
          afterEvaluate {project ->
            if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion 26
                    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
                }
            }
        }
         resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                  && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
               details.useVersion "26.0.2"
            }
         }
      }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-geocoder')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.hypaship;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import com.devfd.RNGeocoder.RNGeocoderPackage;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
import com.evollu.react.fcm.FIRMessagingPackage;
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;

import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
         // Add additional packages you require here
         // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
         return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new FIRMessagingPackage(),
            new RNFirebasePackage(),
            new RNDeviceInfo(),
            new RNGeocoderPackage(),
            new MapsPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }

  @Override
   public boolean isDebug() {
       // Make sure you are using BuildConfig from your own application
       return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
   }
   @Override
    public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running ./gradlew clean from inside the android folder before running the command?

Comment: yes did clean build

Comment: build failed happen when I try to link react-native-fcm library

Comment: This might be the issue. I see that you include both react-native-firebase and react-native-fcm in your build.gradle. You do not need react-native-fcm as you alraedy have react-native-firebase. The packages might interfere with eachother. Try removing react-native-fcm and look into how to achieve the desired functionality in react-native-firebase.